# webserver starts handling requests before IHostedService is started

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac

is there any way to configure .net core / autofac to wait for the HostedService to complete the startup?

boiled down example

```cs
#define useAutofac

public class Startup
{
#if useAutofac
    public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<HostedService>().As<IHostedService>().SingleInstance();
    }
#else
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHostedService<HostedService>();
    }
#endif
}

class HostedService : IHostedService
{
    // snip
}
```

complete sample: [gist](https://gist.github.com/Bonuspunkt/d398da836954b6ca67470ea2f610684a)

without the `#define useAutofac` the execution order is as expected

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely related to how you register the hosted service with Autofac.

Even without the manual registration in `ConfigureContainer`, internally the [`AutofacServiceProviderFactory`](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection/blob/develop/src/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection/AutofacServiceProviderFactory.cs) factory for will extract any registered services in the service collection and copy them over to Autofac's container.

```
 builder.Populate(services);
```

[Source](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection/blob/develop/src/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection/AutofacServiceProviderFactory.cs#L56)

So `Startup` can remain as

```
public class Startup {

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        services.AddHostedService<HostedService>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {

        //...

    }
}
```

with the proper registration and be copied over to Autofac's provider for use.

You can also consider moving that our of the `Startup` and configure it while building the host

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
#if useAutofac
        .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
#endif
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); })
        .ConfigureServices(services => {
            services.AddHostedService<HostedService>();
        })
        .Build();

    await host.RunAsync();
}
```

That way, any hosted services will be started when the host is run.

Comment: not really the execution order is `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` then soemwhere is a `GenericWebHostedService` registered and then `ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)` is executed.
The GenericWebHostedService seems to be the webserver

Comment: @RobertZach Note the line above, ie: `_hostedServices = Services.GetService<IEnumerable<IHostedService>>();`